# PHP load page1, sleep 5 seconds, load page 2

Tags: php, include

I need to do something that in theory sounds very easy but i've been running into alot of issues to get it done correctly.

There's a layer of complexity added because i'm running a custom frauddetection script but that shouldn't have any impact on this.

Basically, I need my PHP code to do the following

-Load Page 1 (through Include() so the URL doesn't change)
-Show that page for 5 seconds
-Stop showing Page 1, and instead show Page 2 (using an Include() again so the URl stays the same)

Any ideas?

Closest i've gotten is this:

```html
<?php
ob_start();
include ("1b.html");
ob_clean();
sleep(5);
include ("1c.html");

 ?>
```

But it just displays nothing for 5 seconds, as if the page is still loading, and then just shows 1c without ever showing 1b for 5 seconds.

Comment: At first glance I'd say you might need to use Javascript and an AJAX call. Or you could preload the content and then have javascript change what is visible. Once the PHP page it loaded it won't be able to reload or load in new content. PHP is server side so once it sends the data to the browser it is done.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible. This is not at all how PHP works. You can't send a blob of data to the user, and then *redact* it and send a new blob of data to the client. Output buffering cannot be used in this way.

> But it just displays nothing for 5 seconds, as if the page is still loading,

That's because the page **is still loading**. You're in the middle of an HTTP request, and you told PHP to `sleep` for 5 seconds.

---

To make this work, you need to send both parts to the client, and **in JavaScript**, programatically hide the first part and show the second after 5 seconds

**Or**

Send the first part to the user, and (either through a meta refresh or JavaScript) reload the page after 5 seconds and use *some* signal such as a query string parameter to session state to serve up the second page of content to the user.

Comment: Thanks, some good suggestions.

Any sample snippet codes for option 2? If I reload the page with a query string, how do I load only the 2nd page without rendering the first page? 

Option 1 doesnt seem like a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
<?php
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['loaded'])) {
    $_SESSION['loaded'] = 0;
}

if($_SESSION['loaded'] == 0) {
    include('page1.php');
}
elseif($_SESSION['loaded'] == 1) {
    include('page2.php');
}
elseif($_SESSION['loaded'] == 2) {
    include('page3.php');
}
else {
    $_SESSION['loaded'] = 0;
    die(header("Refresh:0"));
}

if(isset($_SESSION['loaded'])) {
    $_SESSION['loaded']++;
    die(header("Refresh:5"));
}
```

**- edit:** only once:

```
<?php
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['loaded'])) {
    $_SESSION['loaded'] = 0;
}

if($_SESSION['loaded'] == 0) {
    include('page1.php');
    $_SESSION['loaded']++;
    die(header("Refresh:5"));
}
elseif($_SESSION['loaded'] == 1) {
    include('page2.php');
}
```

Hope I helped :)

Comment: Getting a Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by.. on line 21 (die(header("Refresh:5"));) with this. Already checked for whitespaces and UTF 8 without BOM, so I think it's really the issue of sending the header twice.

Seems to be doing it's job tho. Loads file 1, and if I refresh it loads file 2.

Comment: OK i've got it all working. Only issue I'm having now is that it continuously refreshes the page after 5 seconds. I want it to just refresh once after 5 seconds and then stay on that page. Is that possible?